# PHP Doctrine ArrayCollection deserialization error

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, deserialization

I have this string saved in database, using Doctrine's array type.

```
$test = unserialize('a:10:{s:4:"data";s:12:"registration";s:5:"order";s:4:"desc";s:5:"mySex";i:2;s:3:"sex";s:3:"all";s:6:"ageMin";i:36;s:6:"ageMax";i:46;s:9:"interests";O:43:"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection":1:{s:53:"Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollectionelements";a:1:{i:0;O:41:"Singles\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\Interest":4:{s:45:"Singles\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\Interestid";N;s:50:"Singles\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\Interestprofile";N;s:46:"Singles\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\Interestsex";i:1;s:51:"Singles\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\Interestactivity";i:0;}}}s:14:"onlyWithPhotos";b:1;s:8:"counties";N;s:9:"districts";N;}');
```

It always throws an exception with message:

```
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 261 of 615 bytes
```

That is exactly the semicolon at end of this string:

... Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollectionelements";

What could cause the deserialization to fail? Whenever I exclude the array collection, deserialization works. The serialization is done using doctrine, I don't do it manually.

Comment: Do all of the referenced entities still exist?

Comment: @localheinz the entities serialized are not persisted in the database, their id in the string is N (null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Output of [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) is binary string, which can contain `null bytes` – eg `\x00`. Deserialization fails because of you are passing string trimmed of that `null bytes`, so string size of FQCN doesn't match. Eg:

```
->  Size is set to 53:
-> …ArrayCollection":1:{s:53:"Doctrine\Common\C…
->  But it is 51:
-> …ArrayCollection":1:{s:51:"Doctrine\Common\C…
```

Comment: Thanks! This was the solution! I have used a function here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148712/regex-code-to-fix-corrupt-serialized-php-data to fix the length of elements, after that unserialize worked.

Comment: @tomazahlin if you want to avoid this issue, you can use `base64_encode` after serialization, and before unserialize `base64_decode`.