# How do I search and replace a string that occurs multiple times throughout an object, in both values and keys?

Tags: php

I want to replace all instances of a particular string in an object which includes properties, values and keys that include this string, including within longer keys/values that contain this string amongst other information.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
$amended_object = str_replace('search', 'replace', serialize($object));
$object = unserialize($amended_object);
```

So I turn the object into a string, search and replace, and convert it back.

However I often get `Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset` when the object is in a particular state, and it seems like it's not a very good solution.

Comment: When you serialize you get something like `s:5:"value"` which means `string:length 5:"value"`.  So if you change `value` to `bob` it is no longer length `5`.

Comment: Assuming the object is just a standard stdClass then you are much better off using `json_encode()` and `json_decode()`. Additionally If you are searching or replacing an escaped character then you need to respect it all the way through.

Comment: Bahh, that was my answer...  ^^^^^ Use this as it doesn't store types or lengths.

Comment: @AbraCadaver My comment was honestly just built as a continuation of yours. You succinctly explained why the error is occurring which is important :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `serialize` you get something like `s:5:"value"` which means `string`:`length 5`:`"value"`.  So if you change `value` to `bob` it is no longer length `5` and `unserialize` will error.

So you would need to correct the string lengths as well.  Try JSON as it doesn't store the types or lengths:

```
$amended_object = str_replace('search', 'replace', json_encode($object));
$object = json_decode($amended_object);
```

Answer (score 1):

Serialize wont work unless you correct the length of the containing string in the entity.

So you take the substring of the entity, split it up by the : sign, count/get the length of the total value string you want to correct and recalculate that with your replacement considered. Then update the stringcontent.

Comment: json_encode (from other answers) wouldn't work for me I think because of the complexity of the object. Correcting the lengths as with your answer worked fine though. Check here for a snippet to recalculate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5581004/7253130

Comment: I remember that one but couldn't find it as a duplicate.